# Restore from incremental backup?

Tags: rsync, backup, restore, dump

I  read some books which use `dump` and `restore`. They said that during restore, first restore the latest full backup, and then restore each incremental backup created after the full backup.

But I am using `rsync`. If I am correct, it does incremental backup by hard links to previous backup.

- Then when restore, can I just do one restore: copy the latest incremental backup? Because this will in turn copy the previous backup it hard-links to?
- Can I also delete the backups older than the last one? Because hardlinked files won't be deleted if they are still hard linked? How can we write a script to automatically remove older backups, so that only the most recent 2 or 3 backups are kept?
- If the answers to the above two are yes, then backup and restore with `rsync` are simpler than `dump` and `restore`.Then why do we need `dump` and `restore`?
  Thanks.

Comment: Tell us **how** you are using `rsync`.